# Why does the text become multicolored when a Windows screenshot is zoomed?

Tags: windows, screenshot, zoom, cleartype

Take a screenshot in Windows:

[image]

Now, zoom it:

[image]

Why does the text become multicolored whereas it should only be black? Is this related to ClearType?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Cleartype works by using the red, green, and blue subpixels separately to achieve a finer resolution (http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartypeinfo.mspx).
So the text is already multi-colored before you magnify it,
it's just not noticeable in a standard viewing distance
(but
if you use a magnification glass, you will probably see it).

For instance, the greenish line right of the vertical stroke of T is the result of pixels in which the left (red) subpixel is switched off (like in the black pixels left to it), but the middle (blue) and right (green) subpixels are switched on (like in the white pixels right of it).